# ASP.NET [Route("api/dvds/search")] function does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am making an ajax call to 'http://localhost:44315/api/listings/search', which can take in four parameters, such as title, releaseYear, director, and rating, but everytime I call the route, when debugging, the function `Search()` never gets called. I have also tried postman, but it seems like whatever tool I use, it just hangs and fails to reach the path. If you know another way of setting this route, I would like to know.

Here is my **ListingsAPIController.cs**

```
public class ListingsAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/dvds/search")]
        [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
        public IHttpActionResult Search(string title, int? releaseYear, string director,
            string rating)
        {
            var repo = DvdRepositoryFactory.GetRepository();

            try
            {
                var parameters = new ListingSearchParameters()
                {
                    Title = title,
                    ReleaseYear = releaseYear,
                    Director = director,
                    Rating = rating
                };

                var result = repo.Search(parameters);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Views/Listings/Search.cshtml**:

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
                search();
                return false;
            });
        });

        function search() {            
            var params;

            params = 'title=' + $('#title').val() + '&releaseYear=' + $('#releaseYear').val() + '&director=' +
                $('#director').val() + '&rating=' + $('#rating').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:44315/api/dvds/search?' + params,
                success: function (results) {
                    console.log("search");
                    $('#searchResults').empty();

                    $.each(results, function (index, dvd) {                        
                        var html = '<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-4 col-md-4">' +
                            '<div class="card" style="border:2px solid #0094ff; width: 20rem; border-radius: 5px; ">' +
                            '<div class="pl-3 pt-1 text-center">' +
                            '<h4 class="card-title text-primary">' + dvd.Title + '</h4>' +
                            '<p class="recentListing">' + dvd.ReleaseYear + '</p>' +
                            '<p class="recentListing">' + dvd.Director + '</p>' +
                            '<p class="recentListing">' + dvd.Rating + '</p>' +
                            '<p class="recentListing">' + dvd.Notes + '</p>' +
                            '</div>';

                        $('#searchResults').append(html.toString());
                    });

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error performing search, try again later!')
                },
                done: function () {
                    alert('Search AJAX complete')
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

I have tried renaming the route from `listings` to `dvds`, but still getting error.

**UPDATE:** What I have learned is that Visual Studio 2019 has forced projects to use the "Configure for HTTPS" option when changing **Authentication** to "Individual User Accounts". HTTP used to be the default for older versions.

[image]

Comment: What's the error you getting? If u set a parameter in you error function you can see the error in your alert.

Comment: yes it takes a while for it showup, error: 'Error performing search, try again later!'

Comment: it doesnt really feel like the route is listening to anything, I just wish there was a way to see a list of routes that are listening to see if the route is actually correct. I know in asp.net core I can run the cli, but I am not sure if you can do this asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `http` while your api at `https` so in your search page call https

```
url: 'https://localhost:44315/api/dvds/search?'
```

or just delete the base URL :

```
url: '/api/dvds/search?'
```

Check your query maybe you have an error in SQL